# TFS - TF209026 - ItemNotFoundException

Tags: tfs, build

I try to execute a build batch on my build Agent, the following error I get:

TF224003: An exception occurred on the build computer : TF209026: An un
expected error occurred on the Team Foundation server http://tfsserver:8080/: Item
NotFoundException The item %2f%2f&changesetVersion=35&deletionId=0
 does not exist at the specified version

I have noticed that the map on the server is created but the TFSBuild.proj is not placed from source control.

Somewhere it went wrong, I have no clue what goes wrong.

Comment: If you go back to the Edit Build Definition dialog, does TFSBuild.proj exist in the specified location?

Comment: Yes, it exists in source control on the specified location.

If I look on the server where msbuild creates the map 'BuildType', the map is empty. TFSBuild.proj is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue.

Security settings are the issue.

I added to the TeamProject specific group Membership 'Build_accounts' but that was not resolution. I had to give the TFSBuild.proj explicitly rights, I added via Source Control right on the TFSBuild.proj file.

I thought that when the TeamProject has the correct group memberships it wil automatically give TFSBuild.proj file the correct group memberships.

Comment: Sounds like something has screwed up your security permission tree.